# Java question on building HashMap for multiple enums

Tags: java

I'm making an RPG game in Java for a school assignment. In the game I take user input and the first word is the "command word", so I create an enum to convert the strings for user input to enum constants:

```
public enum CommandWord
{
    GO("go"), QUIT("quit"), HELP("help"), BACK("back"), LOOK("look"), DROP("drop"), GRAB("grab"), USE("use"), UNKNOWN("?");

    private String commandString;

    /*
     * Initialize with the corresponding command string.
     * @param commandString the command string.
     */
    CommandWord(String commandString) {
        this.commandString = commandString;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return commandString;
}
```

Sometimes the second word is a direction following "go" so I have a second enum for directions with more constants:

```
UP("up"), DOWN("down"), NORTH("north"), SOUTH("south"), EAST("east"), WEST("west"), UNKNOWN("unknown");
```

I'm trying to come up with the best method for building a HashMap to store strings and the related enum constants. For command words I have this class:

```
public class CommandWords
{
    // A mapping between a command word and the CommandWord
    // that is associated with it
    private HashMap<String, CommandWord> validCommands;
    /**
     * Constructor - initialise the command words.
     */
    public CommandWords()
    {
        validCommands = new HashMap<>();
        for (CommandWord command : CommandWord.values()) {
            if(command != CommandWord.UNKNOWN) {
                validCommands.put(command.toString(), command);
            }
        }
    } 

    /**
     * Searches the HashMap of valid commands for the supplied word.
     * @param commandWord The word we're searching for.
     * @return The CommandWord that is mapped to the supplied string commandWord,
     *         or UNKNOWN if it is not in valid command.
     */
    public CommandWord getCommandWord(String commandWord)
    {
        CommandWord command = validCommands.get(commandWord);
        if (command!= null) {
            return command;
        }
        else {
            return CommandWord.UNKNOWN;
        }
    }
}
```

Then I can take userinput and search for the command word, but I can't reuse it for directions, or items, characters etc. I looked at using a generic class but I can't call methods like .values() on it, is there a good way to do this so I can reuse the CommandWords class on different enums?

Comment: Well, you could have `CommandWord` be an interface and let all enums implement that. Then you'd need to determine what type `command` is or call methods that the interface defines. When doing that enums might not be the best way to implement commands but discussing that might be out of scope for this question. As an alternative you could have multiple maps that handle each individual type - after all you'd need to know the type anyways, i.e. if you get `go down` then the first would be the command and the second would be the direction (which you know because of the "go" command).

Comment: out of wonder, why you want to have sigle map for all your enums? what s your gain here?

Comment: sorry wasn't clear, I wanted to have multiple maps like <String, CommandWord> and <String, Direction> but I'm wondering if I can have a class like CommandWords that can make maps for all enums

Answer (score 0):

We have **valueOf(String)** method on Enum, you don't have to build that map.

For your case, you have a value, and you know which Enum type you would like to convert to. So, just use:

```
CommandWord.valueOf("QUIT");
Items.valueOf("GEM");
etc..
```

Enums must be determined at compile-time.